# Properly Update A Timestamp's Timezone

Tags: php, xml, last.fm

I'm using the LastFM API to extract a user's recently listened-to tracks (http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks) and am struggling to shift the timestamp to match my preferred timezone.

I've used **date_default_timezone_set** at the beginning of the code, but that seems to be ignored when I use **strtotime**. I'm using **strtotime** so that I can reformat the styling of the date as Last.FM provides it.

I've figured out how to manually offset to the correct time, via *$date - 14400*, but I'd like to understand what I'm missing and make the adjustment in the correct way.

Code follows. Greatly appreciate any assistance.

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New York'); ?>
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=rj&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
echo '<ul>';
foreach($xml->recenttracks->track as $track) {
    $title = $track->name;
    $date = $track->date;
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date("F jS, g:i a e", $date);
    $string = '<li>'.$title.' - '.$date.'</li>';
    echo $string;}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you shared what date strings last.fm actually returns, for those of us who don't use it... However, it'd appear they're providing a UTS timestamp in the `<date>` as an attribute, so there's no need for strtotime - you've already got the parsed date available in GMT-0

Comment: Thanks, Marc. An example of a returned date string is _3 Oct 2012, 03:47_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default timezone you set is used for both the incoming and outgoing translation.

To solve, use PHP timezone functions, and flip it about when reading / writing the time:

```
$oDateTime = new DateTime($track->date, new DateTimeZone(UTC'));
echo $oDateTime->format('F jS, g:i a e') . "\n";  // For debug: Will give the same back at you.

$oDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New York'));
$date = $oDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";   // Will give the converted date
```

(You can also do it with date_timesone_set, but this looks neater).

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will be really helpful.